# C# In Memory Assembly to DLL File

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to save an Assembly to a file using System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder but it's not working.

I've got a variable to hold an assembly that is running perfect when I load and run it.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly dll = GetAssembly(resource);
```

Is there anyone who can help me to save this "dll" into a file like "name.dll"?

Comment: Which GetAssembly method is that?

Comment: this is private function. it returns correct assembly. I am not sure how to save this assembly.

Comment: Well the private method clearly knows how to get the data... so why not use the same logic? (Extract it into a common method.)

Comment: the private method gets data from bytes stored in a resource file, convert it to assembly and then store in a variable. I am looking for a way to save this data for future use by just referencing it via Add Reference in VS

Comment: See my answer. If that doesn't help, you need to give us a *lot* more context about what you're doing. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you've said that the private `GetAssembly` method fetches data from a resource file and builds an assembly from it. Assuming the "bytes" it's getting from the resource file really are just the bytes of the assembly, the simplest way of getting a file is to get those same bytes from the resource file, and call `File.WriteAllBytes`. You don't need to go via an `Assembly` object, and doing so makes the job harder.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AssemblyBuilderAccess` flags must be `RunAndSave` or `Save` for it to work.